# How can I influence the notification of sms app?

Tags: java, android

I need to read text of incoming messages and decide whether to display a notification or not for that message. I have read through other questions but I couldn't find any possible solution. If its not possible to do so, some ideas to work around this problem would be really appreciated.

What I basically want is to read messages that fall into a particular category and indicate the results to the user.

Comment: Since KitKat, you can't do anything about the default SMS app's `Notification` unless your app is the default. You can still receive and read incoming messages if you're not the default, but you can't "influence" how another app issues its own `Notification`s.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Notificatiion Listener API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) in Android. It will allow you to listen to notifications and from there you should be able to determine if it is relevant to you and then do whatever action you need.